# Islam and Christianity in Lebanon

Tags: religion

In this article was the following.

And the bold line surprised me quite a bit because here it says that some Christian factions are for both Sunni and Shiite parties. Am I mistaken in my understanding?

But why is it possible that Christian parties can be aligned with any Muslim political party?

Lebanon, since its creation as a modern state, in 1943, has never been disassociated from events in Syria, with a largely sectarian divide between those who support Assad—the Shiite parties of Hezbollah and Amal—and an anti-Assad coalition of Sunnis and Druze. **(There are Christian factions aligned with both.)**

Comment: (1) Clan politics; (2) ethnic politics - remember that the christians still fit in ethnically with many Muslim groups; (3) Tactical political considerations.

Comment: I'm going to share this with Christianity.SE & Islam.SE

Comment: Which article is *this article* ?

Answer (score 2):

In Lebanon (and in some other places) 'Christian' is as much an ethnic and cultural as a religious designation. Members of groups labelled 'Christian' may or may not believe in God, follow the teachings of Jesus or attend church.

Given that, there may be many reasons to ally with one faction or another that have nothing to do with religion.

Answer (score 2):

Christians and muslims in Lebanon both are separated internally in their political point of view toward Syria. One part of Christians believe that the downfall of the Syrian governement will affect Lebanon. This part is aligned with the Shiite parties of Hezbollah and Amal. The others see Syria as the enemy to be destroyed. because of its alliance and support to Hezbollah and Amal (the Shiite part).